# Implementing classes, Triangle isosceles

Tags: java, geometry, implementation

I need to implement a Triangle class and im stuck on comparing the lengths of the sides to determine if the triangle is indeed an isosceles. Here is what I have so far:

```
public class TriangleIsosceles {

    private Point cornerA;
    private Point cornerB;
    private Point cornerC;
    private int x1;
    private int y1;
    private int x2;
    private int y2;
    private int x3;
    private int y3;

    public TriangleIsosceles(){
        cornerA = new Point(0,0);
        cornerB = new Point(10,0);
        cornerC = new Point(5,5);
    }

    public TriangleIsosceles(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3){
        cornerA = new Point(x1,y1);
        cornerB = new Point(x2,y2);
        cornerC = new Point(x3,y3);
    }

    public String isIsosceles(String isIsosceles){
        return isIsosceles;
    }

}
```

The `Point` object im using is this:

```
public class Point {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(){
        this(0,0);
    }

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void setX(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }
    public void setY(int y){
        this.y=y;
    }
    public void printPoint(){
        System.out.println(x + y);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "x = "+x+" y = "+y;
    }

}
```

In another class (`LineSegment`) I created a method `length()` that determines the distance of two points. Which looks like:

```
public double length() {
    double length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2) + Math.pow(y1-y2,2));
    return length;
}
```

How can I use this method to help me find the lengths of the triangle in my `TriangleIsosceles` class?

I know I need to see if `(lenghtAB == lengthBC || lengthBC == lenghtCA || lengthAB == lengthCA)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick, perfectly valid, solution would be to make your length method a static utility method, i.e.

```
public static double length(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));
}

or

public static double length(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(p1.x - p2.x, 2) + Math.pow(p1.y - p2.y, 2));
}
```

You could also add the method to Point itself, i.e. in the Point class add:

```
public double calcDistance(Point otherPoint)
{
   return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - otherPoint.x, 2) + Math.pow(this.y - otherPoint.y, 2));
}
```

Comment: [Point2D#distance(Point2D)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(java.awt.geom.Point2D) Seems like it would be a lot easier, no?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would most likely implement it, and is what I show as the third solution above. I just wanted to give a few alternatives for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `LineSegment` class has a constructor that takes two `Point` objects, you should create three `LineSegment` objects (which you can cache in the `Triangle` class).  Then using `LineSegment#getLength()` you can determine if any two sides are the same length.

Since this looks like homework I won't give you the full solution.